# Tell latexmk that either of two targets is enough

Tags: latexmk

I have a setup in which running an external program can produce either a `pdf` file or a `png` file. Unfortunately, latexmk thinks there is a missing target and stops rather than running `latex` a second time to incorporate the newly produced targets. As a consequence, I can get the correct result after running latexmk a second time, but that sort of goes against the whole point of using latexmk to begin with.

**How do I modify the latexmkrc to indicate that an asy file should result in either a pdf or png file (but not both)?**

Minimal (non-)Working Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{asypictureB}
\begin{document}

This is from a pdf:

\noindent\def\asywidth{5cm}
\begin{asypicture}{name=pdf_example,width=\asywidth}
  settings.outformat="pdf";
  size(@asywidth,0);
  draw((0,0)--(100,0));
\end{asypicture}

\bigskip
This is from a png:

\begin{asypicture}{name=png_example,width=\asywidth}
  settings.outformat = "png";
  settings.render = 16;
  size(@asywidth,0);
  import three;
  draw(unitsphere);
\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

with latexmkrc file

```
$pdf_mode = 1;

# Copied from https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/HEAD/doc/latexmkrc
sub asy {return system("asy -o '$_[0]' '$_[0]'");}
add_cus_dep("asy","eps",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","pdf",0,"asy");
add_cus_dep("asy","tex",0,"asy");
```

(P.S. I'm aware that asypictureB is designed to be used with shell-escape rather than latexmk, but as the author of said package, I'd like it to be versatile.)

Comment: This *feels* impossible from what I know of latexmk. Maybe as a workaround, consider instead of writing `settings.outformat="png"`, specify it as an option to `asypicture` environment (or an option that can be configured globally), and when generate the asy file then *prepend* the line `settings.outformat=⟨output format⟩`?

Comment: Another workaround would be to rename both the PDF and the PNG file to some common extension e.g. `.asyout` using the custom build rule itself. Assuming `\includegraphics` doesn't mind incorrectly-named file extensions.

Comment: @CharlesStaats: I've looked at this a bit, and found something of a solution.  The subroutine for the custom dependency can detect the changed extension of the output file and take suitable action.  But latexmk doesn't fully adapt to the new situation.   Perhaps you could contact me at the address in the latexmk documentation, since my initial solution isn't suitable for being made public.

Comment: (for what it's worth I don't really care that much about using asypictureB with latexmk --- quite the opposite, I use asypictureB to avoid the full latexmk run because of some temporary configuration that I use a script that emulate a small subset of latexmk --- but that isn't very relevant to this question)

Comment: @user202729: I had in mind when writing this package that, as one use case, it would make usage with `latexmk` more convenient in particular when you insert an image in the middle of a long document (provided you give that image a name). If we could get that behavior to work properly, I think it would be a good thing.

Comment: I agree that getting this to work would be a good thing.  There is, in fact, an `asymptote_latexmkrc` file in the latexmk distribution, but it doesn't cover the situation in this question (and needs better robustness).